# ECS Elitegroup KV2 lite 1.0 Motherboard doesn't detect SATA drive and takes forever to load BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata, hardware-detection

my problem is as follows:

I was connecting a (bootable) SATA hard drive to the 'ECS Elitegroup KV 2 lite 1.0'
in my friends rig, which already had two IDE hard drives (one with bootable Windows XP) and a CD-ROM drive installed.

When I started the PC first after connecting all cables it (expectedly) did not boot into Windows, but  (unexpectedly) also took forever to load the BIOS and the SATA drive was not even recognized. On top of that, instead of any BIOS Post messages I only see a giant logo screen of my motherboard while changing boot priority doesn't change a thing with the no-booting issue.

I also have tried to boot Linux from USB to further analyze the problem, but it doesn't seem to boot on this system either.

Any idea what to do?

---UPDATE---
Somehow I finally managed to boot Kali Linux from USB. Linux doesn't recognize any hard drives either.

Comment: New m/b? Sounds a bit like a hardware issue, if you'd get a Linux up and running (yeah, I saw your remark) by tinkering with the boot (kernel) parameters, you might be able to diagnose it better. Linux tends to be pretty chatty about hardware issues it finds.

Comment: Got to boot Kali Linux now, but it doesn't detect the drives, too.

Comment: If the firmware hangs at or takes very long for hard disk detection, the drive is likely to be broken. You could try another port and/or cable.